# Determine the stability of the equilibria

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

I'm given a discrete dynamical system in which $f$ is given by $$f(x,y)=(1+y-ax^2,bx). a,b \in \mathbb{R}, b\neq 1$$

I'm asked to find the equilibria which I have done below:

$$f(x,y)=(x,y)  $$
$$\Rightarrow 1+y-ax^2=x \text{ and } bx=y$$
$$ \Rightarrow ax^2-(b-1)x-1=0$$

$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{(b-1) \pm \sqrt{(b-1)^2+4a}}{2a}$$

Next I'm told that when $a=\frac{-(b-1)^2}{4}$ there is only one equilibrium. I'm asked what can be said about it's stability.

I have found that the equilibrium is $x=\frac{b-1}{2a}.$

To determine its stability I have found $f'(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} -2ax & 1 \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

At the equilibrium position this is $\begin{pmatrix} 1-b & 1 \\ b & 0\end{pmatrix} $

Then $\det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix} 1-b-\lambda && 1 \\ b && -\lambda \end{vmatrix} \Rightarrow \lambda=\frac{1-b \pm \sqrt{(1-b)^2+4b}}{2a}=\frac{-2\big(1-b \pm\sqrt{(1-b)^2+4b} \big)}{(b-1)^2} $

What do I do next?

Comment: If you are assuming $a=-\frac{(b-1)^2}{4}$ why are you still having both $a$ and $b$ in your formulas?

Comment: Indeed, substitute in this expression everywhere you see $a$ and you can start to say something about the the magnitude of $\lambda$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I've made the necessary substitutions in my formula for $\lambda$, I'm still not sure what I can say about the absolute value of $\lambda$ though. I know that a solution is stable if the eigenvalue is less than $1$ in modulus and unstable otherwise, I'm just not sure how to determine this.

Comment: Take the modulus, set it to be less than 1, solve for $b$. This will tell you for which values of $b$ the system has a stable equilibria. Replacing $b$ by the expression involvig $a$ and then solving for $a$ will give you restrictions on $a$ required to have a stable equilibria.

Comment: Why don't you simplify the expression for $\lambda$? You can remove the square root

Comment: @MarcoDisce Could you explain this further please? Perhaps as an answer?

Comment: $(1-b)^2+4b=1-2b+b^2+4b=\ldots$